# using the same pointer for two functions in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I am using the same pointer for two functions,

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function to generate and return random numbers */
int * getRandom( ) {

    static int  r[10];
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        r[i]=i*2*i*9183784;
        printf( "r1[%d] = %d\n", i, r[i]);
    }
    return r;
}

int * geti( *p) {
    static int  r[10];
    int I;

        r[i] = p[i]*i;
    printf( "r2[%d] = %d\n", i, r[i]);
    }

    return r;
}

int main () {
    int *p;
    int i;

    p = getRandom();
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf( "*(p + %d) 1: %d\n", i, *(p + i));
    }

    p = geti(p);

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf( "*(p + %d) 2: %d\n", i, *(p + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It becomes the following output:

> r1[0] = 0
>   r1[1] = 18367568
>   r1[2] = 73470272
>   r1[3] = 165308112
>   r1[4] = 293881088
>   r1[5] = 459189200
>   r1[6] = 661232448
>   r1[7] = 900010832
>   r1[8] = 1175524352
>   r1[9] = 1487773008
>   *(p + 0) 1: 0
>   *(p + 1) 1: 18367568
>   *(p + 2) 1: 73470272
>   *(p + 3) 1: 165308112
>   *(p + 4) 1: 293881088
>   *(p + 5) 1: 459189200
>   *(p + 6) 1: 661232448
>   *(p + 7) 1: 900010832
>   *(p + 8) 1: 1175524352
>   *(p + 9) 1: 1487773008
>   r2[0] = 0
>   r2[1] = 18367568
>   r2[2] = 146940544
>   r2[3] = 495924336
>   r2[4] = 1175524352
>   r2[5] = -1999021296
>   r2[6] = -327572608
>   r2[7] = 2005108528
>   r2[8] = 814260224
>   r2[9] = 505055184
>   *(p + 0) 2: 0
>   *(p + 1) 2: 18367568
>   *(p + 2) 2: 146940544
>   *(p + 3) 2: 495924336
>   *(p + 4) 2: 1175524352
>   *(p + 5) 2: -1999021296
>   *(p + 6) 2: -327572608
>   *(p + 7) 2: 2005108528
>   *(p + 8) 2: 814260224
>   *(p + 9) 2: 505055184

these can not be the numbers mathematically for instance in *(p + 5) 2. Where is the problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code for `geti()` doesn't compile; there's a stray `}` before the `return r; }` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing integer overflow.  The values you're trying to calculate don't fit into 32-bit signed integers.  For instance, r2[5] is meant to be 459189200 * 5, which is 2295946000.  But the largest positive value that can be represented in a signed 32-bit integer is 2**31 - 1, which is 2147483647.  So it comes out as 2295946000 - 2**32 which is -1999021296.

You could represent the desired value in a 32-bit unsigned integer, but that would only get you one value further.

If your compiler supports a 64-bit `long long` data type, that would solve your problem.  Beyond that, you could either use floating point (but you would eventually lose precision in the low-order bits), or switch to an extended-precision integer representation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is the integer overflow. The calculated results do not fit into the `int` value. The 64 bit `long long` would allow proper calculations.

This is the modified program with test results (gcc 7.2.0 on 64 bit Mac):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function to generate and return random numbers */
long long * getRandom(long long r[])
{
    //static int r[10];
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        r[i]=i*2*i*9183784;
        printf( "r1[%d] = %lld\n", i, r[i]);
    }
    return r;
}

long long * geti(long long *p) { // declare the type
    //static int  r[10];
    int i; // i

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
       p[i] = p[i]*i;
       printf( "r2[%d] = %lld\n", i, p[i]);
    }

    return p;
}

int main () {
    long long *p;
    int i;
    long long  r[10];

    p = getRandom(r);
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf( "*(p + %d) 1: %lld\n", i, *(p + i));
    }

    p = geti(p);

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        printf( "*(p + %d) 2: %lld\n", i, *(p + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
r1[0] = 0
r1[1] = 18367568
r1[2] = 73470272
r1[3] = 165308112
r1[4] = 293881088
r1[5] = 459189200
r1[6] = 661232448
r1[7] = 900010832
r1[8] = 1175524352
r1[9] = 1487773008
*(p + 0) 1: 0
*(p + 1) 1: 18367568
*(p + 2) 1: 73470272
*(p + 3) 1: 165308112
*(p + 4) 1: 293881088
*(p + 5) 1: 459189200
*(p + 6) 1: 661232448
*(p + 7) 1: 900010832
*(p + 8) 1: 1175524352
*(p + 9) 1: 1487773008
r2[0] = 0
r2[1] = 18367568
r2[2] = 146940544
r2[3] = 495924336
r2[4] = 1175524352
r2[5] = 2295946000
r2[6] = 3967394688
r2[7] = 6300075824
r2[8] = 9404194816
r2[9] = 13389957072
*(p + 0) 2: 0
*(p + 1) 2: 18367568
*(p + 2) 2: 146940544
*(p + 3) 2: 495924336
*(p + 4) 2: 1175524352
*(p + 5) 2: 2295946000
*(p + 6) 2: 3967394688
*(p + 7) 2: 6300075824
*(p + 8) 2: 9404194816
*(p + 9) 2: 13389957072
```